# How to perform key revocation in spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server with nimbus JWKSource<SecurityContext>

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, security

tl;dr:

- How to change keypair without downtime using `nimbus JWKSource<SecurityContext>`
- How to arrange a `JWKMatcher` that is accepted by a `JWKSelector` to get all existing keys?

## Setup

- Java : 21
- Spring Boot : v3.2.x
- spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server : 1.2.x

  - com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.*

## Reference

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/reference/getting-started.html

Given code in reference (March 2024)

```java
    @Bean 
    public JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource() {
        KeyPair keyPair = generateRsaKey();
        RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
        RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();
        RSAKey rsaKey = new RSAKey.Builder(publicKey)
                .privateKey(privateKey)
                .keyID(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .build();
        JWKSet jwkSet = new JWKSet(rsaKey);
        return new ImmutableJWKSet<>(jwkSet);
    }
```

The code gives an example how to generate and store keys.

## Scenario

- Spring uses `com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.JWKSource` to store keypairs.
- The JWKSource is immutable (`ImmutableJWKSet<>(jwkSet)`).
- In case of key revocation/rotation e.g. after a TTL of the key, there is a short period with two keys to prevent downtime.

  - Old key, which shall be deleted shortly.
  - New key, which has just replaced the old one.
- The transition period is set to 5 minutes (for this example).

  - Connected systems are informed that the old public key shall not be used anymore.

    - Requests using the old (public) key are still accepted.
  - Connected systems are informed that they shall collect the new public key.

    - On request only the new (public) key is delivered.

## Hurdle

As the JWKSource is *immutable* it has to be `rewritten completely` to ...

- add a new key.
- delete an old key.

This feels dirty, especially as key `-revocation` or `-rotation` is a standard procedure in my eyes.

## Effective problem

... ignoring the dirt and force head through ...

### Trying to rewrite the `JWKSource`

To my recent knowledge the `JWKSource` offers a *get()-function*, which returns a list of keys.

- `List<JWK> get(final JWKSelector jwkSelector, final C context)`

Herein the `JWKSelector` needs `JWKMatcher`.

**I fail interpreting the docs**

How to arrange a `JWKMatcher` that is accepted by a `JWKSelector` to get all existing keys?

In the first place all keys are needed to be retreived, so they can be rewritten to a `new JWKSource` using the keys UUID.

## Alternative, but not persued

If downtime is not critical, the `JWKSource<SecurityContext>` can just be overwritten with a new keypair.
Systems using the old keypair`s publickey will bounce until they use the new one.

This is likewise a system restart.

## Final thoughts

It feels like this is the right spot (spring security) and at the same time the wrong way (JWKSource).

---

Thanks for reading & happy for help   :)